# WCF Service calling a Java Service. Should it be async?

Tags: wcf, async-await

I currently have an application whereby a user makes a request to my ASP.Net UI, which in turns makes an async call into a WCF service to keep the ASP.net thread free.

The WCF service is essentially a translation module, sat on the restricted network, and bridging the DMZ to the Trusted network. This service calls out to a Java service, which will hit the DB, and I currently have this as a synchronous call.

My WCF services are setup with `ConcurrencyMode.Single`, and `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`, so I guess that when I run out of threads on the service host, I'll start backing up requests because the UI is calling async, allowing the user to send multiple requests.

Should I be calling the Java service as an async task, like I do in the UI?

Comment: Bare in mind that you are calling a SOAP over HTTP service. The technology used to implement it on the other side of the HTTP channel is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async-await` is almost always a good idea. It doesn't really matter which IO you are using (in this case a network call to a java service) as long as it can benefit from treating it as an asynchronous by releasing threads while waiting for IO to complete.

Of course you would get a bigger benefit by also making the java service fully asynchronous, but it isn't necessary.